# Using One Thymeleaf Form for Partial Table Update and @OneToMany Persistence with Validation

Tags: spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have a `user` table and a `user_details` table. The `user` table gets partially populated by a script and the remaining `age` and `birthplace` values get added manually by a user via a Thymeleaf form. As a part of the form I also want to add details in the `user_details` table. The relationship is a @OneToMany.

I am running into a few issues with Validation that I am not able to figure out properly:

1. Since only 2 fields of the 5 are in the form to save to table `user`, is using hidden inputs the best way to pass all the User field values to the save method in the event of a validation failure or is the a cleaner way (i.e., a JPA annotation type way, etc.)?
2. On the initial loading of the user, the UserDetails are iterated through in the user.html file with `th:each="detail: ${user.userDetailsById}"`. However, when the save method fails validation and the user.html file is returned from the `result.hasErrors()` block, those details revert to null and do not display. Do I have to manually query those again?
3. The object in the form is a User object. If I want to pass a `user_details` comment in the form input how would this be structured and persisted into user.user.userDetailsById.comment?

I've included the code below.

```sql
    create table user
    (
        id         varchar(10)  not null
            primary key,
        first_name varchar(100) not null,
        last_name  varchar(100) not null,
        age        int unsigned null,
        birthplace varchar(100) null,
        constraint user_id_uindex
            unique (id)
    );
    
    create table user_details
    (
        id       int unsigned auto_increment
            primary key,
        user     varchar(10) null,
        comments longtext    null,
        constraint user_details_id_uindex
            unique (id),
        constraint user_details_user_id_fk
            foreign key (user) references user (id)
    );
```

```java
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name = "user", schema = "demo")
    public class User {
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 10)
        private String id;
        @Basic
        @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 100)
        private String firstName;
        @Basic
        @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 100)
        private String lastName;
        @Basic
        @Column(name = "age", nullable = true)
        private Integer age;
        @Basic
        @NotEmpty
        @Column(name = "birthplace", nullable = true, length = 100)
        private String birthplace;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userByUser")
        private Collection<UserDetails> userDetailsById;
    }
```

```java
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name = "user_details", schema = "demo")
    public class UserDetails {
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        private int id;
        @Basic
        @Column(name = "user", nullable = true, length = 10)
        private String user;
        @Basic
        @Column(name = "comments", nullable = true)
        private String comments;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private User userByUser;
    }
```

```java
    @Controller
    public class UserController {
    
        private final UserRepository userRepository;
        private final UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;
    
        public UserController(UserRepository userRepository, UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository) {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
            this.userDetailsRepository = userDetailsRepository;
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/all")
        public String getAllUsers(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("users", userRepository.findAll());
            return "users";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/{id}")
        public String getUser(@PathVariable("id") User user, Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            return "user";
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/save")
        public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "user";
            }
            userRepository.save(user);
            return "redirect:/all";
        }
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Users</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <main class="container p-5">
    
        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Birthplace</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
                            <td><a class="text-dark" th:href="@{'/' + ${user.id}}" th:text="${user.id}"></a></td>
                            <td th:text="${user.firstName}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${user.lastName}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${user.age}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${user.birthplace}"></td>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot></tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    
    </main>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Users</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <main class="container p-5">
    
        <section>
    
            <p th:text="'User: ' + ${user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}"></p>
    
            <!-- THE USER DETAILS BECOME NULL WHEN THE VALIDATION RETURNS BACK TO THE FORM -->
    
            <div th:if="${user.userDetailsById}">
                <div th:each="detail: ${user.userDetailsById}">
                    <p th:text="'Comment: ' + ${detail.comments}"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
        </section>
    
        <section>
            <form action="#" th:action="@{'/save'}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    
    
                <!-- ARE MULTIPLE HIDDEN INPUTS THE BEST WAY ENSURE THAT WHEN VALIDATION FAILS THE TABLE FIELDS GET PASSED BACK TO THE FORM? -->
    
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{firstName}">
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{lastName}">
    
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="mt-3">
                            <label class="form-label" for="age">Age</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="age" type="number" th:field="*{age}">
                            <div class="text-danger mt-2" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}"
                                 th:errors="*{age}"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="mt-3">
                            <label class="form-label" for="birthplace">Birthplace</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="birthplace" type="text" th:field="*{birthplace}">
                            <div class="text-danger mt-2" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('birthplace')}"
                                 th:errors="*{birthplace}"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
    
                <!-- HOW DO I IMPLEMENT THIS 'ADD USER DETAILS' INPUT TO POPULATE A NEW COMMENT TO THE USER DETAILS? -->
    
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="mt-3">
                            <label class="form-label" for="userDetail">User Details</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="userDetail" type="text" th:field="*{????????}">
                            <div class="text-danger mt-2" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userDetail')}"
                                 th:errors="*{??????????}"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <div class="mt-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-dark w-100" type="submit">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <div class="mt-3">
                            <a class="btn btn-secondary w-100" th:href="@{/all}"
                               role="button">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    
    </main>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When offering a form with a partial edit on an entity I would personally use a seperate bean for the form submit with only the editable fields and a hidden id field, then in the service layer find the entity with that id and edit it's values depending on what was submitted in the form.
2. No you don't have to manualy query the fields again. The reason those fields are empty is because they'r not correctly bound when posting the form aslong as you post them with your form they wil come back when you return an error.
   List fields need a name like `*{userDetailsById__[iter.index]__.comments}` where iter comes from the each loop `th:each="iter, detail: ${user.userDetailsById}"`. for more details on how to do this you can look at  https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list#list-selection-expression
3. see 2

P.s. You don't need the SQL in your question nor the overview page html as they do not relate to the question your asking. Just the edit page html, controller and entities (and service if relevant) is enough I'd say